# ASP.NET MVC - Open Table in new window and print

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and have a table with 9 columns which shows results from the database where the user can filter values based on columns. The table structure looks like this:

```
<table class="tableMain" id="x">
        <thead>
            <tr class="trMain">
                <th class="thMain">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
            </th>
            <th class="thMain">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YEAR)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="trMain">
                <td class="tdMain">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                </td>
                 <td class="tdMain">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YEAR)
                 </td>
                 <td class="tdMain">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCheckBoxId" name="airlineId" value="@item.ID" />
                </td>
                <td class="tdMain">
                    @Html.ActionLink("EditValue", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I need a button, so that the dynamically generated table opens in a new window and the print dialog opens automatically. I had this piece of code:

```
<div class="line-btn">
    <input type="submit" value="print" onclick="printTable()" class="btn fl btn-print">
</div>

<script language="javascript">
function printTable()
{
    var printContent = document.getElementById("x");
    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';

    var num;
    var uniqueName = new Date();

    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();var printWindow = window.open(num, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');

    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

The problem here is that the table is completely unsorted when printed so the rows/columns are shifted.

I found this example:

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html

This is exactly what I need (open the table in a new window and open print dialog). But unfortunately this sample has a lot of code in the javascript files that I don't need. There is a search field included and a pagination.

Can someone help me please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a good solution.

This is the code I used:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    var myApp;
    myApp = (function (app) {
        $('#x').click(function () {
            myApp.print();
        });

        app.print = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/Print',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (myApp.arePopupsBlocked()) {
                        alert('please allow popups.');
                    }
                    var printWindow = window.open();
                    if (printWindow) {
                        $(printWindow.document.body).html(data);

                    } else {
                        alert('please allow popups.');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        };

        app.arePopupsBlocked = function () {
            var aWindow = window.open(null, "", "width=1,height=1");
            try {
                aWindow.close();
                return false;
            } catch (e) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        return app;
    })(window.myApp || {})
</script>
```

and right before the table-tag the link to click:

```
<style>
        /* suppress link for printing */
        @@media only print {
            a {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <a href="#" style="font-size: 17px;" onclick="window.print(); return false;">[print table]</a>
```

There opens no new window but the table is well formated for printing.